# Mostrar Registros del usuario Logueado

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```js
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("conexion.php");

$MySQLConnection = new ConnectionDB();
$MySQL = $MySQLConnection->getDBConnection();
$MySQL->set_charset('utf8');

session_start();

if( $_SESSION['user']){

    $user = $_SESSION=['user'];

    $sqlid_user= "SELECT id from usuarios WHERE nombre='$user'";
    $res = $MySQL->query($sqlid_user);

    $iduser=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)["id"]; //convertir array a string

    $sql = "SELECT incidencias.id ,incidencias.titulo, estado.nombre,incidencias.descripcion, incidencias.prevision_cierre, prioridad.nombre, categorias.nombre , usuarios.nombre, usuarios.email
    FROM incidencias
    INNER join prioridad on incidencias.id_prioridad=prioridad.id
    INNER JOIN categorias on incidencias.id_categoria=categorias.id
    INNER JOIN usuarios on incidencias.id_gestor=usuarios.id
    INNER JOIN estado on incidencias.id_estado=estado.id
    WHERE usuarios.id = ".$iduser."";

    $res2 = $MySQL->query($sql);
    $jsonData = array();


    while ($row = $res2->fetch_array()) {
        $jsonData[] = $row;
    }


    echo json_encode($jsonData);
}
```

Alguien sabría hacer la consulta:

Quiero mostrar las incidencias que ha insertado cada usuario, es decir mostrar las incidencias por el nombre de usuario o id:
Adjunto imágenes útiles a continuación.

> **Pd:** He intentado sacar la consulta pero me muestra una incidencia.

[image: Base de datos]

Comment: Hola, pon el código como texto pulsando en [edit]. Las capturas de imagen dificultan la lectura e impiden tomar el código para reproducir el problema. Por otra parte, ¿revisaste tus datos? ¿los JOIN se cumplen para que arroje más de una fila? Puedes probar a cambiar por `LEFT JOIN` **temporalmente, para hacer debug**, pues puede que alguno no se cumpla y por eso no ves las filas que esperas.

Comment: pongo el codigo como texto y pruebo lo que me has dicho, gracias

Comment: El resultado con LEFT JOIN es el mismo

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que te muestra una incidencia te refieres a que muestra una sola fila o a que muestra un error?

Comment: Si lo que muestra es una sola fila, puedes probar la consulta manualmente en la base de datos. Así, vas uniendo las tablas una por una, por ejemplo partes de este pungo: `SELECT * FROM incidencias LEFT JOIN usuarios on incidencias.id_gestor=usuarios.id WHERE usuarios.id = AQUIELID;` Si te muestra una sola fila, entonces revisa que `incidencias` tenga más de una fila con ese valor, si te muestra más de una fila, agregas el siguiente `JOIN` (usa `LEFT JOIN` en esta etapa de depuración y ve agregando uno por uno y prueba), en el `JOIN` en que empiece a arrojar una sola fila estará el problema.

Comment: También puedes mostrarnos una incidencia que estas seguro que debiera regresar la consulta pero no lo hace.